# How to display 2 flexdashboard gauges side by side in Rmarkdown HTML?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have two `flexdashboard` gauges that I would like to plot side-by-side in an Rmarkdown -> html file. The file is **NOT** meant to be a flexdashboard, just trying to use the pretty gauges from that package.

````
---
title: "Eye Gaugeing"
author: "Databot"
date: "10/24/2016"
output: html_document
fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
gauge1_data <- 95
gauge2_data <- 63
max_data <- 100
```

## Gauges
```{r gauge, fig.width=2, fig.height=2, fig.cap='Cap1'}
gauge(round(100*(1.0*gauge1_data)/max_data,2),0,100, symbol = '%', label= "Non-Stops: Tile 1", gaugeSectors(
  success = c(80, 100), warning = c(40, 79), danger = c(0, 39)))
```
```{r gauge2, fig.width=2, fig.height=2, fig.cap='Cap1'}
p0 <- gauge(round(100*(1.0*gauge2_data)/max_data,2),0,100, symbol = '%', label= "Full Cabin Match: Tile 1", gaugeSectors(
  success = c(80, 100), warning = c(40, 79), danger = c(0, 39)))
```
````

[image: Aprox Ouput]
<sup>I like big gauges and I cannot lie.</sup>

Surprisingly, I'm having a hard time getting them side by side. 
Tried to use `library(gridExtra)` but it only likes to arrange things called `grobs`. Gauges are class `htmlwidget` & `gauge`.

Also tried `{r out.width=c('500px', '300px'), fig.show='hold'}` and cramming them both in the same chunk but got an error.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns, please note the `output: html_document` above. I find flexdashboard outputs too confusing. The intended output is not a (flex)dashboard, just trying to use the gauge() functionality of that package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gauges in flexdashboard are specifically for use with the flexdashboard layout system and won't generally work as expected in other formats (that's why the widget is part of flexdashboard rather than in a standalone package).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the gauges to be side-by-side by creating two columns using [HTML/Bootstrap framework](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp):

````
## Gauges

<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-6">
<center>
```{r gauge, fig.width=2, fig.height=2}
gauge(round(100*(1.0*gauge1_data)/max_data,2),0,100, symbol = '%', label= "Non-Stops: Tile 1", gaugeSectors(
  success = c(80, 100), warning = c(40, 79), danger = c(0, 39)))
```
</center>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-6">
<center>    
```{r gauge2, fig.width=2, fig.height=2}
gauge(round(100*(1.0*gauge2_data)/max_data,2),0,100, symbol = '%', label= "Full Cabin Match: Tile 1", gaugeSectors(
  success = c(80, 100), warning = c(40, 79), danger = c(0, 39)))
```    
</center>
</div>
</div>
````